# How do I use space and non-ascii characters in .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess

in .htaccess imposibla use space, non-Latin characters and etc. ?
For example how, fix this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/new user/(.*)$ /page/?id=$1 [QSA,L,E]
```

this decision is not me:

```
... /new_user/ ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the reserved characters for URIs with their respective character codes in percent-encoding, e. g. `%20` for a space.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for more details.

Comment: I see that you're only providing an example, but last time I checked, a space was an ASCII character =)

Answer (score 0):

OK .. signs allowed in url:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm
and in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(([0-9]+)-)?new_user(-([0-9]+))?/?$   new_user.php?page=$2&id=$4 [L]
```

change `www.blabla.com/10-new_user-5`
to     `www.blabla.com/new_user.php?page=10&id=5`

Answer (score 0):

The URL is automatically decoded before your rules operate on it, so you can test against literal characters, e.g. `français\ español` (note that you need to escape literal spaces with a backslash, unless the pattern is quoted).

However, based on your example, I think your actual concern is being able to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/.*$ /page/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
#                    ^---^
#                       it doesn't matter what the user name is, as long as it
#                       doesn't contain a slash
```